# Android FCM, can I send a data message every 5 minutes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

It's simpl question. I don't need code examples or somethings. 
Can I send a data message from my backend every 5 minutes? Is there a Google rules forbidding it?
Are there any limits for sending notifications?
I searched on the firebase site, but I could not find anything about the restrictions.

Answer (score 4):

Well there is no rule which restricts you to send the FCM push so frequently. What would impact is the ability of receiving push by your app.

With introduction of doze mode, Google has placed several restrictions on how freely you can perform background processing. Although high priority FCM messages are delivered even during doze mode, but if they don't end up in user interaction they will be deferred.

Based on [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message):

> High priority messages generally should result in user interaction
>   with your app. If FCM detects a pattern in which they don't, your
>   messages may be de-prioritized.

Android P comes up with priority buckets. If your app falls in Rare bucket, then high priority notifications drops to a limit of 5 a day.